# trouble making AJAX call from client using JQuery and Server using ExpressJS

Tags: jquery, json, express

I am trying to send JSON data from a client using JQUery to a server using ExpressJS on NodeJS. But I'm getting an error:

Client code:

```
var data = {
    title: "title",
    message: "message"
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/testData',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Server code:

```
app.post('/testData', function(req, res) {
var x = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(x); 
});
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)
at C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\app.js:63:22
at callbacks (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.logger (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\logger.js:158:5)
at next (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
```

I'm also not able to parse individual values from the JSON for working on  - on both sides.

-- update --

Although the above problems is solved, I'm not able to send complex objects like

```
var data = {
    num1: 100,
    num2: {
        num3: 100,
        num4: 250
    }
};
```

The server can read num1 from body.num1 but cant read num3 and num4 from body.num2.num3 and from body.num2.num4. The console.log on that just shows "[object][object]"

Comment: Is it already an object because you have set up `bodyParser()` in that case you dont have to parse body using JSON.parse(req.body). What does console.log(req.body) say? http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: Did you try using `app.use(express.bodyParser())` before `app.use(app.router)`

Comment: Thanks! That did solve the problem, for sending a single level hierarchhy of JSON. But compex JSON objects like the ones shown above still cant be sent.

Comment: It should not be an issue. I have used for much more nested and complex ones. Did u stringify the req.body and see how it appears

Comment: Anything else that could help you diagnose?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42428/discussion-between-eternallycurious-and-psl)